# Intershop 7.10. - Checkout without payment

Tags: payment, checkout, intershop

In our scenario, it is possible to checkout a cart with a total amount of 0. This means customer should get the item in the cart delivered for free. In this scenario, we would like to skip the payment method selection process, because there is nothing to pay. However, if we don't set the payment method on the basket, we get the following error during order creation:

```
ERROR localhost ES1 appserver0 [A1-Tomato-Site] [-] com.intershop.component.payment.internal.PaymentServiceBORepositoryImpl [] [Storefront] [0UvmbhgLZVNpN0RNBTznbhh0ZbMJmKzzPr1Slvf9] [tBhm31xHBmEBAAB_-0-00] "tBhm31xHBmEBAAB_-0-00" No payment method is applicable for basket
```

From the following debugger screenshot it is visible that Total Amount on the basket actually is 0:

[image]

Is there some preference that we should toggle or some way to skip the payment selection process for baskets that doesn't require payment processing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check that you have the zero total payment enabled for your channel. You can enabled this payment method in Operation and then configure it in the channel. Intershop should then selected this as the default payment method if the total is zero.

[image]

I haven't tested this with the rest apis, but should work the same as the normal storefront.

Comment: But still, you'll see the payment page. Maybe one can leverage the accelerated checkout by adding the payment method to the basket in case there the basket has a zero total.

Comment: That can be. What I was thinking is the pipeline ViewCheckout-AdjustJumpStep would fast forward him in the checkout if the payment is zero. You would then likely need to modify this pipeline (see extension point VerifyBasketPayments) to set the zero payment method and let it forward you to the next step.

Comment: Nah, its fine, we have a customized checkout process anyway, so skipping a step is not a problem. We only had a problem because no selection was done since the step was skipped and orders would not get created. We have enabled the zero invoice method as you have suggested and automatically preselected it when total amount of basket is zero and it is working perfectly now. Thank you for your help.